# Javascript On blur event

Tags: javascript, onblur

I've got the following code:

```
<span style="margin:0px 2px 0px 2px;">
    <asp:Label ID="labelPromptText" runat="server" Text="Selected Location:" />
    <span id="spanSelectedLocation" style="padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="javascript:SetBackgroundColor('spanSelectedLocation', '#E0E0E0');" onmouseout="javascript:SetBackgroundColor('spanSelectedLocation', '#FFFFFF');" onclick="ControlLocationsVisibility();">
        <asp:Label ID="labelDisplay" runat="server" Text="None" Font-Bold="True" />
        <img alt="Click to change" src="Images/downArrow.png" />
    </span>
</span>

<asp:Panel ID="panelLocations" runat="server" DefaultButton="buttonFindLocation" style="position:absolute;border:solid 1px #E0E0E0;padding:10px 5px 5px 10px;background-color:#F7F7F7;width:350px;display:none;" >
    Search: <asp:TextBox ID="textboxLocationSearch" runat="server" />

    <asp:Button ID="buttonFindLocation" runat="server" Text="Find" OnClick="buttonFindLocation_Click" />

    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:ControlLocationsVisibility();"

    <hr />

    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewLocations" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeViewLocations_SelectedNodeChanged" NodeIndent="10"></asp:TreeView>
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to be able to hide the panelLocations when someone clicks off of the panel. I tried putting an onblur event of the panelLocations but it always disappears when the TreeView is clicked on.

How can I hide the panel when someone clicks outside of it but not inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use setTimeout() and clearTimeout() you can use the blurevent like you mentioned, but clear the timeout when anything inside the panel gains focus. That way, the only time the event would execute would be when it "really" lost focus.

Comment: can you give me a little bit of an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your other alternative, is to handle onclick events on the body, but that could get slow fairly quickly. If you were to go that route, it would look something this like:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hide Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="first">
    <p>This is the first div.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <p>This is the second div.</p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var first = document.getElementById("first");
  var second = document.getElementById("second");
  var isChildOf = function (ele, parent) {
    if (ele.parentNode === null) {
        return false;
    } else if (ele.parentNode === parent) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return isChildOf(ele.parentNode, parent);
    }
  };
  document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    if (isChildOf(e.target, second)) {
        console.log("Hiding second.");
        second.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        console.log("Showing second.");
        second.style.display = 'block';
    }
  };
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya, i really don't want to go this route because code is in an ASP.Net user control that will be used through-out the website and I can't make another user put all that in their code on every item of their page